# Numbers not creating a line graph

Tags: numbers, iwork

I'm quite new to Numbers (and spreadsheets programs in general) but I need to create a simple line graph based of a spreadsheet but for some reason Numbers is not making the lines of the graph even though the data is there.

[image: The data is selected and I don't know why the lines aren't showing]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Click the edit data reference button. Then see what cells are feeding your chart. Usually this is a result of trying to change the data and ending with none selected.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard to say from the picture you have shared but you may not be doing anything wrong at all. Here is a chart I created with similar data with yours.

[image]

I just selected the numbers to be charted (but did not select either the header row or the header column) and then clicked on Chart in Numbers toolbar at the top and selected the icon representing the 2D line chart.

Numbers behave in a weird fashion sometimes in creating charts in my experience. This happens to me occasionally even when I am creating simple charts. When this happens, I create a new file, copy the data only to the new file and create a new chart usually using the same steps. Those steps that have failed in my first trial usually work in the second trial!

Answer (score 0):

To plot in Numbers you need to select two columns and then insert a chart. Makes sure the chart type is a line plot or scatter plot. Then the plot should appear. If not check your axis and see if they are scaled properly. It sounds confusing but it's really easy. I've made many plots using Numbers so if you need additional help just add a comment. I'll try to help.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for trying to help, that's what I did, I clicked on the spreadsheet and clicked on to make a line graph and it does create one but doesn't show the lines (as you can see in the photo) I think that it has something to do with the data maybe, im using very small numbers and for some reason the vertical axis is showing numbers form 0 to 4 when I have numbers smaller then 0

Comment: If you click on the graph and then on the right side click on the axis tab at the top. This is where you can set the max and min values of each axes.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your table and for me, the chart just happened automagically. I had the entire table selected, rather than any specific rows/columns/cells.

Maybe you should also check if the data format of the cells is set to numbers, and not text or something else? The way it is left-aligned makes me kind of suspicious of that.

[image: Select the entire table]
[image: Choose 2D Line Chart]
[image: Suddenly, chart.]